# populate listview dialog with data from sqlite database

Tags: android

I am creating android app where a user saves some items into a sq-lite database. i want to display that data in a list view dialog so he can select an item on click. how do i accomplish that.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class extending CursorAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html and provide instance of this class to the AlertDialog.Builder setAdapter method.

```
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
                //handle item selection
            }
        }
    });
```